# How to get the last 3 group created at the same time?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the last 3 groups of coupons created at the same date. My table looks like so:

```
+-------------+-----------+
|coupon name  |Created at |
+-------------+-----------+
|c1           |2016-01-17 |
|c2           |2016-01-17 |
|c3           |2016-01-18 |
|c4           |2016-01-19 |
|c5           |2016-01-19 |
|c6           |2016-01-20 |
|c7           |2016-01-20 |
|c8           |2016-01-20 |
|c9           |2016-01-20 |
|c10          |2016-01-21 |
|c11          |2016-01-21 |
+-------------+-----------+
```

My result should be:

```
+-------------+-----------+
|coupon name  |Created at |
+-------------+-----------+
|c4           |2016-01-19 |
|c5           |2016-01-19 |
|c6           |2016-01-20 |
|c7           |2016-01-20 |
|c8           |2016-01-20 |
|c9           |2016-01-20 |
|c10          |2016-01-21 |
|c11          |2016-01-21 |
+-------------+-----------+
```

I have looked for the same question but I couldn't find any.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.`coupon name`, t1.`Created at`
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT `Created at`
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY `Created at`
  ORDER BY `Created at` DESC LIMIT 3
) AS t2 ON t1.`Created at` = t2.`Created at`
```

The above query uses a derived table that contains the last three days of your table. We can get the last three groups of coupons by joining to this in-line table.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c858/2)